# multiple modules in GWT

Tags: gwt

I know there are many questions concerning this topic but after reading them all I'm even more confused.

I have an application that manages contacts. There are three pages:

- Add contact
- Show contacts
- Modify contact

And now I have no idea what structure to give to my project: should I create three different modules? if so, what would be the best package structure? and how would I call other modules within a page? for example, from the 'add contact' page there should be a button to the 'show contacts' page, and from this one there should be button/links to 'modify contact' and 'add contact'.

would it be enough to add this line to the corresponding buttons event handlers?

```
Window.Location.assign("showcontacts.html");
```

(or just create a link to "showcontacts.html" if it's the case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow multiple pages to be selectively displayed within a single module, I use one of two techniques:

1. use a SimplePanel or one of its
   derivatives (e.g. LazyPanel,
   ScrollPanel).Use setWidget to change
   the page. Each "page" is a widget.
   For example, I am doing a project
   with a menubar. When "Home" menuitem
   is clicked, the menu command
   replaces the body of the simplepanel
   by setting its widget to the Home
   widget. Likewise for login, etc
   menuitems.

   A SimplePanel allows only one widget.
   Therefore, you do not addWidget to it but setWidget to it.
2. use tab. Either TabLayoutPanel or
   TabPanel. I prefer using the
   TabLayoutPanel. You have to meticulously
   set/design the CSS for TabLayoutPanel, otherwise
   you would only see a blob of text hanging around.

I also try to encapsulate a "page" widget in a lazypanel (which is a derivative of a simple panel. That will prevent instantiation of any pages that may not be used in a module with a large number of "pages".

GWT is indeed suitable for ui presentation with multiple pages. In fact, one of the advantages of GWT over JSP is that you can change a page without a browser refresh/fetch flicker - one of the extremely strong reasons why you would want to use GWT for a web app with multiple pages.

Comment: I'm going to try both techniques to see which one I like best, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

GWT is not suited for applications with multiple pages. What you can do is

create a page with multiple div's. Create the links on the top of the page. When any of the link is clicked you can then show or hide divs as per your need. This is how I had done it for a different app.

Hope that helps

Comment: I get what you're saying but I still don't quite understand it. How can the divs be shown or hidden when needed?

Comment: RootPanel.get("yourdiv").setVisible(false);

Answer (score 0):

Seems that GWT MVP framework suits your needs:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Comment: thanks!! i notice that the example they use there is the same I wanted to develop... it's going to be hard not to copy :P

Comment: but that's way too complicated for what i need.
why can't it be done with 
Window.Location.assign("showcontacts.html");???

Comment: It depends on whether you are going to invest into framework learning or not. If it's one-time project it's probably not worth it, but if you want to build the complicated system you should give it a try and decide for yourself if you are happy with framework limitations or not. Actually I don't see a point of using GWT if its possibilities aren't used at 100%.